# Change caption font size

Tags: tables, fonts, captions

I want to change the font size of a single rotated table caption (definitely **not** all the captions in all my tables/figures)

Right now I can wrap the text inside the `\caption` around a `\scriptsize{}` command, but that will change the font also in the *Tables Index* which is **really bad**.

I'm compiling with `pdflatex`.

Here's what the table looks like:

```
\begin{landscape}
 \begin{table}
  \centering
  \footnotesize{
   \begin{tabular}{l|c|c|}
   \hline
   blah & blah & blah
   \hline
   \end{tabular}
  }
  \caption{Lots of words...}
  \label{table-label}
 \end{table}
\end{landscape}
```

Comment: Can you complete your example to a full compilable one with the used packages etc. ?

Comment: I'd love to but I really can't. I'm writing my thesis and the LaTeX template I'm using is enormous with too many new commands defined. I can list the packages I'm using if you think that would help though.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

If your document class is compatible with the [`caption`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/caption) package, you can use its `\captionsetup` command for the particular table (I removed parts of your code not relevant to the caption issue):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

\listoftables

\begin{table}
\captionsetup{font=scriptsize}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{lc}
  \hline
  text & text \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Lots of words...}
\label{table-label}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]