# \hhline double line imperfection

Tags: tables, rules

Using the `\hhline` command i found some imperfection in the double line. How can i fix it?

### Imperfection

[image: Imperfection]

### Table

```
\documentclass[11pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{hhline}                 
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{output-decimal-marker={.}, group-separator={\,}}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{dcolumn}                
\usepackage{multirow}



\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|lr|lr l|} \hline


H       & 5             & $W_N$ & 250       & \si{\gram}        \\
L       & 26            & $W_L$ & 241       & \si{\gram}        \\
P       & \num{3000}    & $C_u$ & 3E{-4}    & \euro/\si{\gram}  \\
$n_C$   & \num{142506}  & $c_0$ & 2E-01     & \euro/pack        \\
$\delta$& 1             & $c_1$ & 5E-01     & \euro/h           \\
\hhline{=====}


&   \multicolumn{2}{c}{$r.s_{std}$} &   \multicolumn{2}{c|}{$r.s_{iter}$} \\

\hhline{=====}

Media(W)    &   \multicolumn{2}{D{.}{.}{3.4}}{245.9463}                                                 &   \multicolumn{2}{D{.}{.}{3.4}|}{245.9459}\\
DevStd(W)   &   \multicolumn{2}{D{.}{.}{3.4}}{3.9932}                                                   &   \multicolumn{2}{D{.}{.}{3.4}|}{3.9939}\\
\emph{f.o}  &   \multicolumn{2}{D{.}{.}{3.4}}{0.27395}                                                  &   \multicolumn{2}{D{.}{.}{3.4}|}{0.27395}\\
$n_B$       &   \multicolumn{2}{D{.}{.}{3.4}}{3000}                                                     &   \multicolumn{2}{D{.}{.}{3.4}|}{3000}\\
$t_{tot}$   &   \multicolumn{2}{D{.}{.}{3.4}}{2612.22}                                                  &   \multicolumn{2}{D{.}{.}{3.4}|}{6906.10}\\

\hhline{=====}

Config.     &   \multicolumn{2}{c}{10 20 40 50 200}                                                     &   \multicolumn{2}{c|}{40 130 130 220 220}\\ \hline

\end{tabular}
\begin{footnotesize}
\caption{Confronto $r.s_{std}$ Vs $r.s_{iter}$ [$C_u > 0$]}
\label{tab:Confronto_rs_C_mag_0}
\end{footnotesize} 
\end{center}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi! You obviously use quite a lot of additional packages. Wouldn't you please mind to convert the code snippet to a [Minimal Working Example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)? Thanks!

Comment: Are readers supposed to understand that `r.s_{std}` refers to the column underneath it? Well, with that table format they won't understand. In Italian one says “Confronto tra A e B”, not “Confronto A Vs B”. If you prefer to use Itanglish, at least write “vs” (lowercase).

Comment: Now the example is working ;) @egreg If you have any sort of suggestions for the table style i'm all ears!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've never seen that command, but I'd replace that with two `\hline` commands, like this:

```
\hline
\hline
```

> [image: image, lines work]

I've changed the style of the table a little bit, in case you don't mind a different solution. The changes I did are:

1. Inserted `booktabs` and removed all of the vertical lines except one in the upper table.
2. Fixed the caption using the suggestion from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/60039/4778) (FIY, now it's actually `footnotesize`, earlier the command wasn't working) and I have shifted it a little bit below.
3. Changed the caption according to egreg's suggestion (I agree with him on that one).

**Doubt**: are they two distinct tables? If the `r.s std` is referring to the lower part, then you should consider adding some whitespace or trying a different solution, as in splitting the tables. Let me know if you want something of that sort.

[image: table 2]

Here is the code (I have written notes for my additions in the code itself):

```
\documentclass[11pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{hhline}                 
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{output-decimal-marker={.}, group-separator={\,}}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{dcolumn}                
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption} % Allows to set the caption font size

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
    \captionsetup{font=footnotesize} % Set the caption font size
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{lr| lr l}

\toprule

H       & 5             & $W_N$ & 250       & \si{\gram}        \\
L       & 26            & $W_L$ & 241       & \si{\gram}        \\
P       & \num{3000}    & $C_u$ & 3E{-4}    & \euro/\si{\gram}  \\
$n_C$   & \num{142506}  & $c_0$ & 2E-01     & \euro/pack        \\
$\delta$& 1             & $c_1$ & 5E-01     & \euro/h           \\

\bottomrule

&   \multicolumn{2}{c}{$r.s_{std}$} &   \multicolumn{2}{c}{$r.s_{iter}$} \\

\midrule

Media(W)    &   \multicolumn{2}{D{.}{.}{3.4}}{245.9463}                                                 &   \multicolumn{2}{D{.}{.}{3.4}}{245.9459}\\
DevStd(W)   &   \multicolumn{2}{D{.}{.}{3.4}}{3.9932}                                                   &   \multicolumn{2}{D{.}{.}{3.4}}{3.9939}\\
\emph{f.o}  &   \multicolumn{2}{D{.}{.}{3.4}}{0.27395}                                                  &   \multicolumn{2}{D{.}{.}{3.4}}{0.27395}\\
$n_B$       &   \multicolumn{2}{D{.}{.}{3.4}}{3000}                                                     &   \multicolumn{2}{D{.}{.}{3.4}}{3000}\\
$t_{tot}$   &   \multicolumn{2}{D{.}{.}{3.4}}{2612.22}                                                  &   \multicolumn{2}{D{.}{.}{3.4}}{6906.10}\\

\midrule % automatically provides a little space before and after it (up and down)

Config.     &   \multicolumn{2}{c}{10 20 40 50 200}                                                     &   \multicolumn{2}{c}{40 130 130 220 220}\\

\bottomrule

\end{tabular}
\vspace{10pt} % a little space to shift the caption down
\caption{Confronto tra $r.s_{std}$ e $r.s_{iter}$ [$C_u > 0$]}
\label{tab:Confronto_rs_C_mag_0}
\end{center}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the corrections! They are not two distinct tables. the upper part contains the parameters for a simulation (aka input), the lower part (from `r.s std` to the end) contain the output. Did you have in mind a better approach to display all the data?

Comment: @gmeroni Honestly not really. I haven't done something like this before as far as I remember. :D If I get some idea, I'll let you know!