# How can I fix the small gaps in \hhline and make it (and double vertical lines) intransparent to particular vertical (horizontal) lines?

Tags: tables, line, hhline

Take a look at this table:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[activate={true,nocompatibility},final,tracking=false,kerning=true,spacing=true,factor=1100,stretch=10,shrink=10]{microtype}
\DisableLigatures[f]{encoding = T1}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\microtypecontext{spacing=nonfrench}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{float}
\geometry{
    left=2cm,
    right=2cm,
    top=2cm,
    bottom=2cm,
    bindingoffset=0mm
}
\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[H]
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{c|c||cc|cc|cc}
            & $\boldsymbol{(1 - \tau_0) i}$ & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{$\boldsymbol{\alpha = 0{,}01}$}} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{$\boldsymbol{\alpha = 0{,}02}$}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\multirow{2}{*}{$\boldsymbol{\alpha = 0{,}03}$}} \\
            $\boldsymbol{i}$ & $\boldsymbol{=}$ & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{}\\
            & $\boldsymbol{0{,}25}$ & $\boldsymbol{n = 0{,}04}$ & $\boldsymbol{n = 0{,}05}$ & $\boldsymbol{n = 0{,}04}$ & $\boldsymbol{n = 0{,}05}$ & $\boldsymbol{n = 0{,}04}$ & $\boldsymbol{n = 0{,}05}$\\ \hhline{=|=#==|==|==}
            $0{,}05$ & $0{,}0375$ & $\infty$ & $\infty$ & $\infty$ & $\infty$ & $\infty$ & $\infty$\\ \hline
            $0{,}06$ & $0{,}0450$ & $42{,}16$ & $\infty$ & $51{,}35$ & $\infty$ & $52{,}85$ & $\infty$\\ \hline
            $0{,}07$ & $0{,}0525$ & $23{,}11$ & $47{,}03$ & $32{,}30$ & $57{,}24$ & $33{,}79$ & $58{,}78$\\ \hline
            $0{,}08$ & $0{,}0600$ & $14{,}69$ & $21{,}97$ & $23{,}89$ & $32{,}19$ & $25{,}38$ & $33{,}37$
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Using `\usepackage{hhline}` enables me to draw a double horizontal line which is transparent for vertical lines:

[image]

It even enables double vertical lines with the help of `#`:

[image]

But taking a closer look reveals that `\hhline` is comprised of several small lines which leave gaps inbetween:

[image]

I would like to get rid of these gaps, but I don’t know how. [This](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/140409/149141) is no solution for me.

Furthermore, I would like the double horizontal and vertical line to **interrupt** all intersecting lines. Also, I would like to deactivate `#` so that neither the double horizontal nor the double vertical line can interrupt each other. This would/should look like this:

```
 ___| |___
 ___   ___
    | |
```

Instead of:

```
 ___|_|___
 ___|_|___
    | |
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `::` to get an open crossing instead of `#` however the lines are made by drawing a line in each cell, so they are separate lines which start and stop at the same point. Some PDF viewers may show a small gap due to rounding to pixel boundaries, some are better at avoiding that.

It would, in principle, be possible to merge adjacent `-` or `=` segments and make a single `\leaders` run across the span, however that would require quite a lot of changes to the package.

Answer (score 0):

For information, in the environment `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`, the vertical rules are not interrupted by the double horizontal rules specified by `\hline\hline`. Moreover, you won't see thin white lines, whatever PDF viewer you use, at all levels of zoom.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\usepackage{float}
\geometry{
    left=2cm,
    right=2cm,
    top=2cm,
    bottom=2cm,
    bindingoffset=0mm
}
\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[H]
        \centering
        \begin{NiceTabular}{c|c||cc|cc|cc}
            & $\boldsymbol{(1 - \tau_0) i}$ & \Block{2-2}{$\boldsymbol{\alpha = 0{,}01}$} && \Block{2-2}{$\boldsymbol{\alpha = 0{,}02}$} && \Block{2-2}{$\boldsymbol{\alpha = 0{,}03}$} \\
            $\boldsymbol{i}$ & $\boldsymbol{=}$ \\
            & $\boldsymbol{0{,}25}$ & $\boldsymbol{n = 0{,}04}$ & $\boldsymbol{n = 0{,}05}$ & $\boldsymbol{n = 0{,}04}$ & $\boldsymbol{n = 0{,}05}$ & $\boldsymbol{n = 0{,}04}$ & $\boldsymbol{n = 0{,}05}$\\ 
            \hline\hline
            $0{,}05$ & $0{,}0375$ & $\infty$ & $\infty$ & $\infty$ & $\infty$ & $\infty$ & $\infty$\\ \hline
            $0{,}06$ & $0{,}0450$ & $42{,}16$ & $\infty$ & $51{,}35$ & $\infty$ & $52{,}85$ & $\infty$\\ \hline
            $0{,}07$ & $0{,}0525$ & $23{,}11$ & $47{,}03$ & $32{,}30$ & $57{,}24$ & $33{,}79$ & $58{,}78$\\ \hline
            $0{,}08$ & $0{,}0600$ & $14{,}69$ & $21{,}97$ & $23{,}89$ & $32{,}19$ & $25{,}38$ & $33{,}37$
        \end{NiceTabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]