# Reduce or delete the label of caption in a figure environment on beamer

Tags: beamer, captions, fontsize

In this code I need to reduce the size of the 'Figure' word figured in the start of caption image.

```
 \documentclass[compress,red]{beamer} 
  \usepackage{etex}
   \mode<presentation>
     \usetheme{Warsaw}
        \usepackage[applemac]{inputenc}%les accents pour mac
  \usepackage{subfigure}
   \usepackage{multicol}
     \usepackage{animate}
    \usepackage{movie 15}
   \usepackage{amsmath}
   \usepackage{epsfig}
   \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage[all,knot]{xy}
    \xyoption{arc}
    \usepackage{url}
    \usepackage{array,ragged2e}
    %\usepackage{multimedia}
     %\usepackage{hyperref}
       \usepackage{setspace}
      \usepackage{multirow} 
      \begin{document}
       \section{section1 }
        \frame[shrink]{\frametitle{Titre de la fenetre}
          \begin{itemize}
          \item<1-4,5> point1
          \item<2-4> point2
           \item<3-4> point3
             \item<4> point4
           \begin{figure}[!h]
            \begin{center}
       \includegraphics[width=3cm,height=3cm]{listefigures/shadow2.png}
   \caption{\tiny Un exemple 2D de la construction d'un \textit{Visual Hull} par     l'approche surfacique ~\cite{phd2}}
   \label{fig211}
\end{center}
    \end{figure}
       \end{itemize}
        }
       \end{document}
```

Comment: Use command \renewcommand{figurename}{\small{Figure}}.

Comment: See this question: [Change caption font size](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/60037/change-caption-font-size)

Comment: @Jesse it does not work

Comment: @osjerick, it does not work. I need to reduce the Figure or Table words not the content of caption. As you see in my example I redice the size of the caption using \tiny

Comment: I think it would be nice to say on the question that you are using beamer, to improve the access for other people.

Comment: @osjerick, what? sorry I do not understand exacly waht do you mean by your comment.

Comment: @phdstudent Sorry! I don't write well in English. I suggest changing the title of the question adding that you are using the beamer class.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using beamer, the caption package don't work well. You must use in the preamble: `\setbeamerfont{caption}{size=\tiny}` to change the size of whole caption, and `\setbeamerfont{caption name}{size=\tiny}` to change the size of the label.

Here a MWE:

```
\documentclass[compress,red]{beamer}
    \setbeamerfont{caption}{size=\tiny}
    \usetheme{Warsaw}
  \begin{document}
    \frame[shrink]{\frametitle{Frame title}
        \begin{itemize}
            \item<1-> One
            \item<2-> Two
            \item<3-> Three
            \begin{figure}\centering
                \includegraphics[width=3cm]{example.png}
                \caption{Caption test}
            \end{figure}
        \end{itemize}
    }
\end{document}
```

Comment: We can also delete the label by using \captionsetup{labelformat=empty} or \caption*{}